# Как обычно организовывают структуру папок (пакетов)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

На какие пакеты обычно распределяют java-файлы в приложении, ну там типа "adapters" или еще какие-нибудь?

[image]

Comment: Папка это модуль, модуль может состоять из подпапок, которые тоже модули, в модулях хранятся сущности, то есть классы, объединенные в данном модуле по смыслу, то есть папки com.gukov.Gui, ...Model, ...Network, ...Core, ...Engine, ...Utils, и т.д. В свою очередь в Gui может быть так Gui.MainMenu, Gui,CustomWidgets и так далее

Comment: посмотрите как это сделал Google для Android'а

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень сильно зависит от того, какую вы выбрали архитектуру и какие используете паттерны. На самом деле, каждый как хочет так и делает. Если мы обратимся к доке от гугла [JetPack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack) и возьмём [GuideLine](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide), который упорно пропагандирует MVVM, то можно придерживаться следующей архитектуры:

```
yourApp:
  di: //если вы используете Dependecy Injection, по сути модели и настройки даггера. С коином ещё не успел познакомиться. Где встречал то модели койна кладут точно также.
  model: //подразумевается слой работы с данными
    models: //подразумеваются ваши модели
     dto: //Data transfer objects
     entity: // или dao немного спорный момент
     vo: //View Objects
    database: // или db слой работы с БД
    repository: // слой работы с репозиторием
    webservices: //слой работы с вебсервисами
  ui: // тут очень сильно разнятся подходы, но в основном это пакет основного экрана и паралельных с ним. Дальше вкладываете по мере необходимости. если экран используется в нескольких местах, вынесите его повыше. Еще момент. я всегда ViewModel храню рядом с экраном частью которого он является. Также и с UI адаптерами (списков, табов и т.д.), кладу их в тот же пакет что и экран на котором он используется ну или здесь папка для адаптеров. Есть выносят его в модель, но как по мне, это не правильно, он работает не станными, а с UI, данные же ему поступают из вне. Но не путайте их с адаптерами для данных, те конечно же в модель.
```

P.S. Это сугубо моё мнение, и каждый может делать по-своему. Я долго искал, как сделать правильно, и после изучения Гайдлайна, о котором я говорил выше, общения с коллегой, пришёл к такой вот конструкции.